# What is the error in my function for parallax scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get some divs to scroll with a different speed than the rest of the page to create a parallax effect.

Here's my JS and HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="background">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/" />
    </div>
    <div class="background">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </div>
    <div class="foreground">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    </div>
    <div class="foreground">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.container>div').each(function () {
        var iniPos = parseInt($(this).css('top'));
        var bgspeed = 0.5; //background speed
        var fgspeed = 0.8; //foreground speed
        var speed;
        if ($(this).attr('class') == 'foreground') speed = fgspeed;
        else speed = bgspeed;
        $(window).scroll(function parallax(iniPos, speed) {
            var top = $(window).scrollTop();
            var pos = iniPos + speed * top;
            $(this).css('top', pos + 'px');
        });
    });
});
```

([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxrthsp5/4/))

But the divs all just scroll with the same speed as the rest of the page, and I'm unable to find out why the new top positions aren't being set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. Inside your `parallax`, `this` refers to `window`, so `$(this).css()` is meaningless.
   You need to define another variable outside the `parallax` function, inside the `.each()`, like

   ```
   var that = this;
   ```

   and then use `$(that)` inside `parallax`.
2. By defining `iniPos` and `speed` as function arguments:

   ```
   function parallax(iniPos, speed)
   ```

   you break those values. `iniPos` will hold the value of a scroll `Event`, and `speed` will be undefined.
   Just omit the two parameters, like

   ```
   function parallax()
   ```

   (You can omit the function name as well, btw.)

Updated JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.container>div').each(function () {
        var iniPos = parseInt($(this).css('top'));
        var bgspeed = 0.5; //background speed
        var fgspeed = 0.8; //foreground speed
        var speed = $(this).attr('class') == 'foreground' ? fgspeed : bgspeed;
        var that = this;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var top = $(window).scrollTop();
            var pos = iniPos + speed * top;
            $(that).css('top', pos + 'px');
        });
    });
});
```

**[ [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxrthsp5/5/) ]**

Comment: Additional question for my knowledge: So there is no way to pass arguments for functions like these?

Comment: There is (have a look at the second signature of [`.scroll`](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/)), but only as `event.data`. You could use `$(window).scroll({ iniPos: iniPos, speed: speed }, function(event) { /* work with event.data.iniPos and event.data.speed */ })`, but I tend to prefer closures.